# Python - Homework assignment for a dynamic dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

"Try to create a dynamic dictionary of some data with repeating keys and one with repeating values, find what is the value that is repeated and how many times it is repeated as a final print for the user"

I have typed the following code as an example:

```
from itertools import chain

# initialising dictionary
ini_dict = {"Name": 'John', "Age": 43, "Name": 'Mark',"Age": 43,"Occupation": "Plumber" }
init_dict2 = {"Name": 'John', "Age": 43, "Name": 'Mark',"Age": 43,"Occupation": "Plumber", "Occupation": "Teacher", "Age": 35}

# printing initial_dictionary
print("initial_dictionary", str(ini_dict))
print("initial_dictionary", str(init_dict2))

rev_dict = {}
for key, value in ini_dict.items():
    rev_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

result = set(chain.from_iterable(
    values for key, values in rev_dict.items()
    if len(values) > 1))

rev2_dict = {}
for key, value in ini_dict.items():
    rev2_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

result = set(chain.from_iterable(
    values for key, values in rev2_dict.items()
    if len(values) > 1))

# printing result
print("resultant key", str(result))
print("resultant key", str(result))
```

This the output:

```
"C:\Python lectures\TestovProekt\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Python lectures/TestovProekt/Homework 6.1.py"
initial_dictionary {'Name': 'Mark', 'Age': 43, 'Occupation': 'Plumber'}
initial_dictionary {'Name': 'Mark', 'Age': 35, 'Occupation': 'Teacher'}
resultant key set()
resultant key set()
```

I need help on what exact code to type so that the final print result is what value is repeated and how many times, cause I'm very new to all this so I don't know exactly I need to type that I am missing.

Comment: It looks like you have been overthinking the assignment completely. You only have to create two dictionaries and observe them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. The second assignment overwrites the first. That's why you get:

```
{"Name": 'John', "Age": 43, "Name": 'Mark'} == {'Name': 'Mark', 'Age': 43}
>>> True
```

Because of that the homework question doesn't make much sense to me

---

Update (see comments)

Here is a way of counting repeating values (in this cases prices) of a dictionary.

```
fruit_prices = {"apple": 5, "banana": 5, "cherry": 1, "durian": 25}

fruits_per_price = {}
# iterate over all fruit, price combinations
for fruit, price in fruit_prices.items():
    if price in fruits_per_price:
        # if you already have a list of fruits for that price, append the fruit
        fruits_per_price[price].append(fruit)
    else:
        # if not, create a new fruit list
        fruits_per_price[price] = [fruit]
        
# the count for each value is now equal to the length of the fruit list
...
```

Comment: It does: I guess that's the whole point of the homework. It shall show, that keys are not repeated but updated.

Comment: that would be evil ^^^

Comment: That's the thing I am not sure what to do to in this case :D

Comment: Ok, maybe you can interpret it like this:
1. Show that repeating keys are updated
2. Take a Dict with repeating values like `{"price_apple": 5, "price_banana": 5, price_cherry: 1}` and show that 5 is repeating two times

Comment: @Raphael yes, I guess that's the real task of the homework. I would do the same to students :P

Comment: I am really sorry as I'm very new to all this, could you help me how to write that code @Raphael

Comment: @tonyalmeida24 I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @tonyalmeida24 you're welcome. If it answered your question it would be kind of you to mark it as accepted :)